# Razor views, displaying a property linked by a foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have two classes `Address` and `State` (with corresponding tables in my database).

**State** has two properties: `Id` and `Name`

**Address** has (amongst others) `StateId` property

Also, in my Address class I have StateId marked as foreign key

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("State")]
public int AddressStateId { get; set; }
```

In my View, when I am displaying the properties of the Address object, how do I display State name instead of `StateId`?  I don't think I need a new property in Address class I think I just need to somehow reference the other table.

The way I am doing it now is

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AddressStateId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `virtual` property of type `State` to the `Address` class

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { set;get;}
    public int StateId { set;get;}
    public virtual State State { set;get;}
}
public class State
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

Assuming, your view is strongly typed to the `Address` entity class, in the view, you can access the `State` navigational property and use it's `Name` property value

```
@model Address
<h1>@Model.State.Name</h1>
<p>Or use the DisplayFor helper</p>
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.State.Name)
```

Comment: Ah right, /facepalm.  Already had the navigation property there just didn't remember to use it.  Also to add, In my controller, when I get the addresses (via my db context variable) I had to add `.Include("States")` as they were not being picked up automatically.  Ex `var addresses= db.Addresses.Include("State");`

Comment: Is your view strongly typed to a list of Addresses ?

Comment: It is typed to a class that contains the Address class and another class.  So I have to access Address properties by Model.Address.<whatever prop>

Comment: I see. Yea, you need to use Include when you want to eager load something. if yo were simply passing list of addresses you do not need to explicitly load it (since it is  a single item/ not a collection)

Comment: can we please write the controller logic as well, bcz what i a doing is this
```
db.DocMasters.Include("ApplicationUser");
                return View(db.DocMasters.ToList());
```
and in view  <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationUser.officerabbr )
        </td>